# How do I delete a directory from Terminal without knowing its name?

Tags: terminal, shell-script

I have a directory which I want to delete. The directory's name is a random string of letters and numbers. I know the path to its parents directory, so how would I recursively delete the contents of this directory?

There are no other files/directories in the parent directory.

I know I have to do something like this:

```
$ rm -r path_to_dir
```

but since I dont have the dir name I am not sure if this would work.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't delete the parent folder, then recreate it?

Comment: @soandos Hahaha now I feel stupid :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `path_to_dir` is the path to the parent directory, you can just do this:

```
rm -r path_to_dir/*
```

The asterisk (`*`) is a wildcard, so that recursively deletes everything under the parent directory. It's easier than deleting and recreating the entire parent directory, especially if for example it has some custom permissions that you want to preserve.

Comment: rmdir path_to_parent/* would work too and is safer because it removes _only_ empty folders, but not recursively (since a folder with a folder in it isn't empty).

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин this would not work for me since the directory contains other files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do something like:

`rm -rf path_name`
`mkdir path_name`

Comment: I am going to accept Indrek's answer since his solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Indrek has a cleaner solution (though mine will work)